# Iceland in March

Tags: camping, hiking, iceland, winter

I want to go to Iceland during my spring break next year, but there isn't a lot of information on what trails are open for a multi-day hike. What is the best way (and how much am I looking at) for transportation to and from a trail head, and any recommendations for trails?

Comment: This question fits better on [Outdoors.SE].  And I hope you realise this is going to be a snowshoe hike.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the [Great Outdoors SE site](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/)